# Preparing weather data tabulated by latitude-longitude for plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, curated-data, geography

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to plot latitude, longitude, and maximum rainfall of hurricane Harvey on a 3D plot. I have gathered all the data inside *Mathematica* using station names and the `WeatherData` function. I am trying to use `ListInterpolation` to smooth the graph I am obtaining from `data`, but the problem is that my data contains latitude and longitude sets as angles in degrees. This is the code I use to obtain my data:

```
coordinates = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];
weatherstations = WeatherData[{coordinates, 400}];
Lat = Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[i]], "Latitude"], {i, 400}];
Lon = Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[j]], "Longitude"], {j, 400}];
dRain = 
  Table[
    WeatherData[
      weatherstations[[k]], "TotalPrecipitation", 
      {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}], 
    {k, 400}];
MaxRain = Table[DeleteCases[Max[dRain[[k]]], _Missing], {k, 400}];
Rdata = DeleteCases[Transpose[{Lat, Lon, MaxRain}], {_, _, _Missing}];
```

[image]

The data can now be plotted using `3DListPlot`; however,
I cant use `ListInterpolation[data]` because the data contains degree symbols. Does anyone know how do I get around this problem? Do you know what I am trying to say?

Comment: `ListInterpolation` is almost certainly the wrong function to use; you'll probably want to try `Interpolation` instead. Could you please update your answer with actual code rather than an image to make it easier to copy? That makes it a lot easier to help out.

Comment: I tried to use `Interpolation` and I came up with an error as well. I can edit and post the code right now for you. Thank you.

Comment: `Interpolation` asks for data in a different format than the one you seem to be using. I'm also not sure if it will accept `Quantity`s, so you may have to convert the coordinates to regular numbers.

Comment: Converting the coordinates to regular numbers? Like degrees to radians? Or is there a way to drop the degree symbol. Btw, to run the code I don't recommend using 400 data points like what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer also relies on retrieving the property "Coordinates" to get the coordinates as real numbers, but it also shows how the code can be written without using "Table" over and over again.

```
dallas = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];

With[{n = 400}, weatherStations = WeatherData[{dallas, n}]];
coordinates = Through[weatherStations["Coordinates"]];
rain =
  WeatherData[#, "TotalPrecipitation", {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}] & /@ 
    weatherStations;
maxRain =
  (Max /@ DeleteCases[Through[rain["Values"]], Missing[_], {-2}, Heads -> True]) /. 
    {"Values" -> 0., -∞ -> 0.};
data = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {coordinates, maxRain}];
```

Now we have data that is all cleaned up and plots nicely. The red sphere floats above the location of Dallas as retrieved in the code.

```
Show[
  ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Ellipsoid[{32.7942, -96.7655, 2.}, .015 {16, 18, 80}]}],
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: plot]

The plot appears to show that the heaviest rainfall was concentrated along a relative short line segment located south-by-southeast of the city center.

#### Update

This update addresses an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

The maximum wind speed at each weather station can be retrieved in pretty much the same way as the rain data, and it can be used to colorize the rain data. Doing so does add a fair amount more work to making the plot.

Here is how I did it. Note that I have changed the rain data dependent variable from amount of rain on the day of it rained hardest to the total accumulation of rain over the interval under consideration. It doesn't have much effect on the shape of the plot, but it does increased the magnitude of the quantities plotted. You can ignore this change if you wish—just substituted `data` from the 1st part of this answer for `rainData`.

```
dallas = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];
With[{n = 400}, weatherStations = WeatherData[{dallas, n}]];
coordinates = Through[weatherStations["Coordinates"]];
dailyRain =
  WeatherData[#, "TotalPrecipitation", {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}] & /@ 
    weatherStations;
totalRain =
  Total[
    (DeleteCases[Through[dailyRain["Values"]], Missing[_], {-2}, Heads -> True]) /. 
      {"Values" -> {0}, {} -> {0}}, 
    {2}];
rainData = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {coordinates, totalRain}];
dailyMaxWinds =
  WeatherData[#, "MaxWindSpeed", {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}] & /@ 
    weatherStations;
maxWinds = 
  (Max /@ 
     DeleteCases[Through[dailyMaxWinds["Values"]], Missing[_], {-2}, Heads -> True]) 
   /. {"Values" -> 0., -∞ -> 0.};
(* 
   the following associates each coordinate with a maxWinds value scaled to lie 
   in the unit interval 
*)
windData = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {coordinates, maxWind/Max[maxWinds]}];
windF = Quiet @ Interpolation[windData];

Legended[
  Show[
    ListPlot3D[rainData,
      (* this is where windF is used to colorize the plot *)
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][windF[#1, #2]] &),
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
      PlotRange -> All,
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}],
    Graphics3D[{Red, Ellipsoid[{32.7942, -96.7655, 3.}, .015 {16, 18, 2 74}]}],
    ImageSize -> 600],
  BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0., Max[maxWinds]}}, 5]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: A, nice application of `Through`. I always kind of forget when to use that one.

Comment: This is awesome! However, the graph looks a bit too...orange. Lets say I want to color code this graph based on the values of `"WindSpeed"`. This means I want higher values of wind speed red and lower values orange. You could gather your data points for wind speed the same as how you gathered them for `"TotalPercipitation"`( just by using `WeatherData`) but how do you add this extra dimension to the graph?

Comment: @HarrisonWhorf. I have updated my answer to address the matter of coloring the surface to show maximum wind velocity.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close, but the data format you're constructing will not work for `Interpolate`. This should get you where you need to be:

```
n = 20;
coordinates = 
  CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];
weatherstations = WeatherData[{coordinates, n}];
coordinates = 
  Table[WeatherData[weatherstations[[i]], "Coordinates"], {i, n}];
dRain = Table[
   WeatherData[weatherstations[[k]], 
    "TotalPrecipitation", {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}], {k, 
    n}];
MaxRain = Table[DeleteCases[_Missing]@Max[dRain[[k]]], {k, n}];
Rdata = DeleteCases[Transpose[{coordinates, MaxRain}], {_, _Missing}];
```

Note that the coordinates are now regular numbers instead of `Quantity` objects (you can convert quantities to numbers with `QuantityMagnitude`). You can now generate an interpolation function:

```
int = Interpolation[Rdata]
```

Note the message that warns you that the interpolation will be 1st order because of the irregular spacing of the grid points. If you want to have a smoother interpolation, you can try to see if `Predict` works on your data:

```
pred = Predict[Rule @@@ Rdata]
```

Note that these 2 work differently if you want to make a prediction. E.g., if you want to predict for the coordinates `{32, -97}`, you do:

```
int[32, -97]
```

or

```
pred[{32, -97}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `"Coordinates"` will give you lat, lon as actual numbers. `Predict` still doesn't work on my data however.

Comment: Because my data is irregularly spaced, can these functions still be used?Perhaps a better way to visualize this data is to plot these point on a map of Texas and color code them based on the value of height. Do you know how do that? The function `GeoGraphics[{GeoBoundsRegion[{{Min[Lat], Max[Lat]}, {Min[Lon], Max[Lon]}}]}]` will display the bounds of my data.

Comment: Well, you don't need to worry too much about the irregular spacing. It's just that the interpolation will be 1st order, so it'll be a bit blocky. And `Predict` doesn't work for you? What version of Mathematica are you on? I'm on 11.2 and if I copy the code above verbatim into a notebook, everything works. If you want to use `GeoGraphics`, I recommend you look at `GeoBubbleChart` (if your version has it). Finally, you can also visialise the data directly with something like `ListPlot3D[Flatten /@ Rdata]`

Comment: I am on version 11.0. I am going to update to version 11.2 right now. Just thinking of it, could I use `linspace` (or another function for that matter) to generate an evenly spaced grid that is the bounds of my longitude and latitude. MATLAB's interpolation function allows you to input your irregularly spaced data and the evenly spaced `meshgrid` to "smooth" out the graph. Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Well, you could do something like `sampleGrid = Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{minX, maxX}, {minY, maxY}}, Into[20]], 1]` for some suitable values for `minX` etc. Then you can resample the function values on that grid with `int @@ Transpose[sampleGrid]` or `pred[sampleGrid]`.